# PLupload filters - FilesAdded event not triggered

Tags: javascript, plupload

I'm trying to filter image files only with `PLupload`. Here is my script `filters` part:

```
filters: {

    mime_types: [

        { title: 'Image files', extensions: "jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp, png" }
    ]
}
```

**Problem:**

I can select `PNG` files, but after I chose `PNG` file - `FilesAdded` event not triggered and `Queue` is empty.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85mh/4/). (try to attach `PNG` file)

Is anyone had this problem before? Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Actually `FilesAdded` event not triggered with `jpeg, gif, bmp, png` files as well. So there was not only `PNG` issue.

Comment: Solution for time being: removed `filters` and added `PHP` `Ajax` file extension checking in `FilesAdded` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it seems, you should try to remove the spaces in the extensions string, like this :

```
    extensions: "jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp,png"
```

see [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85mh/5/)

Comment: @Vaidas you're welcome. I don't really grasp the regexp in plupload sources, but it does not seem to take spaces into account https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/plupload.js#L1224